# Converting all the elements of a list from string to integer in Python

Tags: python

I have a list, say `list_1` which looks like : `['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']`, Now I want to find the average of all the elements of that list. And to do so I need to first convert all the elements to an integer first. I have seen an answer of stackoverflow and was trying that method:

```
print("The list: ",list_1)
total = 0
list_1 = [ int(x) for x in list_1 ]
for ele in range(0, len(list_1)):
    total = total + list_1[ele]
final_res=total/no_of_times
```

This is giving error saying : `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0.93'`

Comment: `average = sum(map(float, list_1))/len(list_1)`

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you're using are floats instead of ints, so use float() instead.

```
list = ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
list = [float(i) for i in list]
print(type(list[0]))
```

output: <class 'float'>

Answer (score 1):

You cant turn a string float into an integer in one step. If they were floats and not strings, you could use `int()` however this would round.

You can use `float` instead.

```
list_1 = ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
print("The list: ",list_1)
total = 0
list_1 = [ float(x) for x in list_1 ]
print(list_1)
```

output

```
[0.93, 1.0, 1.0, 0.93, 0.87]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `float` instead of `int`:

```
list_1_strs = ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
print(f'{list_1_strs = }')
total = 0
list_1_floats = [float(x) for x in list_1_strs]
print(f'{list_1_floats = }')
for ele in list_1_floats:
    total += ele
final_res = total / len(list_1_floats)
print(f'{final_res = :.2f}')
```

**Output:**

```
list_1_strs = ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
list_1_floats = [0.93, 1.0, 1.0, 0.93, 0.87]
final_res = 0.95
```

Note you could utilize `sum` and `map` to calculate the average in a single line:

```
final_avg = sum(map(float, list_1_strs)) / len(list_1_strs)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```py
from decimal import Decimal

lst = ["0.93", "1.00", "1.00", "0.93", "0.87"]
average = sum(map(Decimal, lst)) / len(lst)
print(average)
# output: 0.946
```

Note: we could use floats, but here we're using Decimals to avoid the typical float rounding errors.

Answer (score 0):

Not able to do `int('1.93')` to convert float values, should be using `float('1.93')` instead

Editing from your code:

```
list_1 = ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
print("The list: ", list_1)
total = 0
list_1 = [ float(x) for x in list_1 ]
for ele in range(0, len(list_1)):
    total = total + list_1[ele]
print('Average is', total/len(list_1))
```

Output

```
The list:  ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
Average is 0.9460000000000001
```

Another suggestion with the same output:

```
list_1 = ['0.93', '1.00', '1.00', '0.93', '0.87']
print("The list: ", list_1)
print('Average is', sum([ float(x) for x in list_1 ])/len(list_1))
```